# How to define custom combine predicate?

Tags: java, java-8, predicate

I defined my own predicate:

```
public interface StringPredicate extends Predicate<String> {
```

It works, but if I write:

```
myPred.and( strEl -> strEl != null);
```

the result is a `Predicate<String>` not a `StringPredicate`. How can I define a combine operation as well?

Answer (score 3):

You can define your own `and` method in your `StringPredicate` interface:

```
public interface StringPredicate extends Predicate<String> {
    default StringPredicate and(StringPredicate other) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(other);
        return (t) -> test(t) && other.test(t);
    }
}
```

Now, the following will work:

```
StringPredicate myPred = s -> s.length() > 0;
StringPredicate combined = myPred.and(strEl -> strEl.length () < 5);
```

Comment: There’s no need for `other` to be a `StringPredicate`. There are several advantages when declaring the method like `@Override default StringPredicate and(Predicate<? super String> other)` instead…

Comment: @Holger, good point. just what the benefit of  declaring `StringPredicate` ?

Comment: @HadiJ I don’t know why the OP wants a `StringPredicate`, but on the other hand, I also don’t know why the JDK developers added, e.g. `UnaryOperator<T>` instead of using `Function<T,T>`, as `UnaryOperator` has exactly the same problems if `andThen` or `compose` are used…

Comment: I have my own object string was just an exaple